# External Jar Library not included to apk using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jar

Firstly I know there are similar questions but they are not exact same problem and didn't solve my problem. I found solutions for Eclipse but there is no for Studio. When I add an external library as jar, it throws a Classnotfound exception running code. In the other hand it works fine on desktop module. Is there anyway to solve this problem? Or what is the reason?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @RakshithRavi I managed to solve it but I don't remember the solution, if you wish I can give you read access to the repository, I haven't touched that project for more than 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your project looks like I can only make a couple guesses.

In your app's build.gradle (there is a separate one in a folder below for your project but you can ignore that one for now) file you need to add your jar files to the dependancies.. usually it is done by default like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

this will add all jar files in your libs folder

Normally you would place your jar files in a directory like:

myProjectFolder/app/libs

So make sure the jar files are in a place gradle can find them in

Comment: They are added to project correctly and on desktop module it works fine. The problem is with Android only.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA#running-your-project here it is described how to do that. With a similar workaround you can run any project.

Comment: Interesting. What was the jar file you were trying to add?

Comment: They are kryonet and sax parser libraries

Comment: isn't sax parser built into the android SDK http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Comment: Yes it is. I need to add it for desktop module. And I recognized the problem when I added kryonet.

Comment: try removing the import and having the IDE re auto add it back? I once had the wrong import and sent me down a similar untamed goose chase

Comment: I don't think if it is about imports because it works on desktop module

Answer (score 0):

1. change your **Project View** from **Android** to **Project**.
2. find out your **libs** directory and add **jar** file into it.
3. select this jar and **right-click**, click **Add as a Library**.

Then check your build.gradle, you'll see someting like `compile files('libs/xxx.jar')` in `dependencies`. If not, add it manually.

Comment: It is not working. I have done that before. It works on desktop module but I get a Classnotfound exception on Android.